# Dynamic table binding using JSON and jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, json

I have requirement where I need to show data in HTML in following structure

```
--------------------------------
day1    | day2    | day3 |
---------------------------------
123     | 323     | 12389  
233     | 34234   | 23234
```

Number of days are not fixed. Variables of my Java Object will containing a map. the key of this map is no. of day e.g. day1, day2 etc and value contains a list of id e.g. 1231,5657,26252 etc.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>()
```

How can I draw these using Data Table or plain jQuery. I think currently Data Table does not allow dynamic column binding..:(

Comment: I have few questions: 1. Are the list id size all the same?, 2.What do you mean by draw, you are plotting it with System.out.print? or a Servlet to print? or jsp? 3.Are you willing to use 3 person library?

Comment: define *"dynamic column binding"*

Comment: @PSo list size not same

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. I have just written just a code but without compiling. Please get the logic and test in your environment.

```
 $.ajax({
    "url": 'your_url',
    //Get your json response
    "success": function(json) {
        //Assume you received response like this
        var days =  {
            "day1": ["123", "233"],
            "day2": ["323", "34234"],
            "day3": ["12389", "23234"],
            ......
        }

        var columns = [];
        var dtable = [];
        for(var key in days){
            columns.push({ title: key});
            dtable.push(days(key));
        }

        var params = {
                data: dtable,
                columns: columns
        };
        $('#your_datatable_id').dataTable(params);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Tharsan SivaKumar

Comment: If it's resolved your issue, why don't you vote and accept as valid answer :) ?